# translate phpmyadmin syntax table.field

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, phpmyadmin

I tried to do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM persona ORDER BY ´id´ DESC LIMIT 0,5;
```

But it returns the result as ASC (not DESC)

I tried it using the graphic interface of PhPmyAdmin and finally I got it:

```
SELECT * FROM persona ORDER BY ´persona´.´id´ DESC LIMIT 0,5;
```

**It works perfectly** with that syntax (persona.id), but in the PHP code it doesn't work.-.

How can I translate the PhPmyAdmin syntax (persona.id) to my PHP code without errors?

---

Here is the PHP code:

```
   <?php
                $sql="SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY '".$_SESSION['campo']."' ".$_SESSION['orden']." LIMIT ".$_SESSION['registro'].",5";
                $result = $con->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){ 
                        echo '<tr>
                                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['apellido1'].' '.$row['apellido2'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['nombre'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['telefono'].'</td>
                    }
                }
                mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

I started the session, with session_start(); , etc
The problem is the $sql=.. line, this works but with ASC, if I write:

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY 'persona'.'".$_SESSION['campo']."' ".$_SESSION['orden']." LIMIT ".$_SESSION['registro'].",5";
```

or for example without the '' in persona:

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY persona.'".$_SESSION['campo']."' ".$_SESSION['orden']." LIMIT ".$_SESSION['registro'].",5";
```

it returns an error and doesn't do the query...

thanks for helping me :) lets try it a little more

Comment: `ORDER BY 'table'.'field'` wrong identifiers, use backticks `\`` and remove the quotes around `'DESC'`. Plus just for the heckuvit, `table` is a reserved word ;)

Comment: Ok you've edited it to be as marked above, well you're going to have to show us more code. One/two lines of code isn't enough.

Comment: Thanks for your advices fred, I pasted the most relevant code

Comment: Look at Stack's syntax highlighting. You have a few things missing such as a quote and a semi-colon, and make sure you've started the session. Maybe even a missing comma for `ORDER BY '".$_SESSION['campo']."', ".$_SESSION['orden']."`

Comment: the main problem is the translation of the phpmyadmin syntax like table dot field to the php code

Comment: @yb_esc It isn't "phpmyadmin syntax". It's supported by MySQL in general.

Comment: just `echo($sql);` to see what you actually send to mysql, it'll be easier to see what's gone wrong.

Comment: duskwuff ty for comment, nice for notice it, I know that, but I am spanish and I have little difficulties for expaning it in english hehe

Comment: I am using already a echo of the $sql it prints:
SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 0,5
And the code shows the table as ASC.

Comment: I did some tries more, without success, for example:

$sql="SELECT * FROM personas ORDER BY 'personas'.'".$_SESSION['campo']."' '".$_SESSION['orden']."' LIMIT ".$_SESSION['registro'].",5";

..any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did it, with the `` syntax, instead of ''

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `personas` ORDER BY `personas`.`".$_SESSION['campo']."` ".$_SESSION['orden']." LIMIT ".$_SESSION['registro'].",5";
```

Thanks all for support and the tries :)